# ¿Por qué validar un input de tipo date en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, es6

¿Por qué las personas todavía incluyen código JavaScript para validar los datos cuando se usa un **input type="date"**? Este input muestra el calendario, lo que debería asegurar que se use una fecha adecuada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Además de **poder controlar mejor el formato de la fecha** que te va a poner el usuario y así luego gestionarla bien en tu código, también hay que tener en cuenta **para que navegadores estás desarrollando**, y obviamente poner avisos en caso que no des soporte a esos navegadores viejos.

En el caso del type=date:

- IE 11 y anterior no lo soportan.
- Safari para ordenadores tampoco
- Algunos móviles viejos que vayan con Opera Mini tampoco.

Más información sobre los navegadores que no lo soportan:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 0):

A veces es para detectar la zona regional y así poder restringir el uso de esa web, o también para registrar los datos actuales de tu computadora y compararlos con los del servidor para que no haya algún tipo de fraude, como lo hace Google en los dispositivos móviles.
Si no tienes la hora y fecha correcta en el móvil, google no te deja hacer algunas cosas que tienen que ver con Android y la PlayStore.